# How to solve ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in docker image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

my docker file:

```
# Use the official Node.js 10 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
# RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.3 -g

# add app
COPY . /app


CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**I buiild:**

```
$ docker build . -t myapp
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.051MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:13.12.0-alpine
 ---> 483343d6c5f5
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c731f744759f
Step 3/7 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e1f5f853c8c6
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f831911acf6c
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c18449857dd2
Step 6/7 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b99412d4725
Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e565a34838d5
Successfully built e565a34838d5
Successfully tagged myapp:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Win                                       dows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-r                                       wxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions f                                       or sensitive files and directories.
```

**Run:**

docker run -p 3000 myapp

```
> myapp-fe@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.3/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Compiled successfully!

You can now view rugvista-fe in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.3:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

Visiting: http://localhost:3000/ gives **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any difference when you open it via http://172.17.0.3:3000/ instead of localhost?

Comment: Takes longer to load but result is the same

Comment: @AydinK  I did not read the message, the diff is that I also get a timeout

Comment: If you `docker run -p 3000`, Docker picks a port for you; `docker port` will tell you what it is, but it's more common to `docker run -p 3000:3000` to pick your own host port (the second port must be 3000 to match the process).  In either case, use `http://localhost:...` with the port number.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your docker file before npm start

```
EXPOSE 3000/tcp
```

Modify your `COPY . /app` to `COPY . .`

Comment: Testing it right now, just one question: If I want to deploy this later on, then this probably needs to get removed?

Comment: Is it better ? So you don't remove this line if you deploy your web app within the docker container because it allowed the outer world to connect to your docker network.

Comment: This did sadly not work. Result is the same

Comment: I edit my response I am not 100% sure. Add `RUN ls -lah` to check if you have all your files